# Prototype objects, and object arrays

Tags: javascript, html, oop, object, prototype

If that title made no sense, let me elaborate.

I have a two objects one called *area* and one called *enemy*.

Each area has it's own enemies so I made enemy prototypes for each area.

Next I did an `array.push();` function on each area prototype so if the user clicks a button they'll be shown a list of "area's" they can essentially explore.

the main part that gives me an error is if I try any function like `alert(areas[0].enemies[0].name);`

How can I use a button to display a specific enemy name?

**No jQuery please**

```
function area(name, enemies) {
  this.name = name;
  this.enemies = enemies;
}

function enemy(name, type) {
  this.name = name;
  this.type = type;
}

var cave = new area("Cave", {
  bat: new enemy("Bat", "Flying"),
  snake: new enemy("Snake", "Ground"),
});

var forest = new area("Forest", {
  bear: new enemy("Bear", "Animal"),
  coyote: new enemy("Coyote", "Wolf"),
});

areas = [];
areas.push(cave, forest);

var thatBtn = document.getElementById('thatBtn'),
    display = document.getElementById('display');

thatBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  for (i = 0; i < areas.length; i++) {
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
      liBtn = document.createElement('button');
    liBtn.textContent = areas[i].name;
    li.appendChild(liBtn);
    display.appendChild(li);
    liBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (j = 0; j < areas.length; j++) {
        if (areas[j].name == event.target.textContent) {
          alert(areas[j].name);
          for (k = 0; k < Object.keys(areas[j].enemies).length; k++) {
            alert(areas[j].enemies[k].name);
          }
        }
      }
    });
  }
});

<button id="thatBtn">click here</button>
  <ul id="display">
</ul>
```

Comment: please take the convention for classes/instantiable functions and use a first upper case letter for the name.

Comment: as in area, cave, bat, enemy?

Comment: only for `function Area` and `function Enemy`.

Answer (score 1):

It gives you an error because `areas[0].enemies` is not an array -- it's an object.

```
{
    bat: new enemy("Bat", "Flying"),
    snake: new enemy("Snake", "Ground"),
}
```

Change it to

```
for(var key in areas[j].enemies) {
    alert(areas[j].enemies[key].name);
}
```

Comment: so how would I be able to display a specific objects name or type?

Answer (score 0):

`enemies` is an object and not an array, so you need to iterate through `keys`
and fetch from there and not from index, just updated your snippet with that, however the code can be better.

```js
function area(name, enemies){
    this.name = name;
    this.enemies = enemies;
}

function enemy(name, type){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

var cave = new area ("Cave", {
    bat: new enemy("Bat", "Flying"),
    snake: new enemy("Snake", "Ground"),
});

var forest = new area ("Forest", {
    bear: new enemy("Bear", "Animal"),
    coyote: new enemy("Coyote", "Wolf"),
});
areas = [];
areas.push(cave, forest);

var thatBtn = document.getElementById('thatBtn'),
    display = document.getElementById('display');

thatBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(i=0; i < areas.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        liBtn = document.createElement('button');
    liBtn.textContent = areas[i].name;
    li.appendChild(liBtn);
    display.appendChild(li);
    
    liBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      for(j=0; j < areas.length; j++){
        if (areas[j].name == event.target.textContent){
          alert(areas[j].name);
          var keys = Object.keys(areas[j].enemies);
          for(k=0; k < Object.keys(areas[j].enemies).length; k++){
            alert(areas[j].enemies[keys[k]].name);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="thatBtn">click here</button>
<ul id="display">
</ul>
```

Comment: awesome! thanks!!! and i'm sure the code could be waaay better, as i've only been coding for 2-3 weeks :)

Answer (score 0):

add enemies as an array, no need to have them with "named keys" in an object

```js
function area(name, enemies){
    this.name = name;
    this.enemies = enemies;
}

function enemy(name, type){
    this.name = name;
    this.type = type;
}

var cave = new area ("Cave", [
    new enemy("Bat", "Flying"),
    new enemy("Snake", "Ground"),
]);

var forest = new area ("Forest",[ 
    new enemy("Bear", "Animal"),
    new enemy("Coyote", "Wolf"),
]);
areas = [];
areas.push(cave, forest);

var thatBtn = document.getElementById('thatBtn'),
    display = document.getElementById('display');

thatBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  for(i=0; i < areas.length; i++){
    var li = document.createElement('li'),
        liBtn = document.createElement('button');
    liBtn.textContent = areas[i].name;
    li.appendChild(liBtn);
    display.appendChild(li);
    
    liBtn.addEventListener('click', function(){
      for(j=0; j < areas.length; j++){
        if (areas[j].name == event.target.textContent){
          alert(areas[j].name);
          
          for(k=0; k < Object.keys(areas[j].enemies).length; k++){
            alert(areas[j].enemies[k].name);
          }
        }
      }
    });
    
  }
});
```

```html
<button id="thatBtn">click here</button>
<ul id="display">
</ul>
```

Comment: awesome this is exactly what i was trying to accomplish!

Answer (score 0):

Your primary issue is here:

```
for(k=0; k < Object.keys(areas[j].enemies).length; k++){
  alert(areas[j].enemies[k].name);
}
```

The expression `Object.keys(areas[j].enemies)` returns an array of object properties, but then you try to iterate over the object using *k*, not the property name.

Since *Object.keys* returns a array, you can use array methods so change the loop to:

```
Object.keys(areas[j].enemies).forEach(function(name) {
  alert(areas[j].enemies[name]);
});
```

You have a secondary issue that you aren't declaring the counters (*i*, *j* and *k*) used in loops so they become globals when the code runs. Declare them like:

```
for (var i=0; i < areas.length; i++) {
```